# Get layout as desired on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an xml file like this. On vertical orietation everything is looking perfect. But when the orientation changes, i dont get a layout as i desired,means things are not aligned.How can i make it correct.Thanks in advance

```
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg"    
   android:orientation="vertical">

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageVi" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:src="@drawable/header" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
 <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRowe"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="50dip">
           </TableRow>
  <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRowe"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="550dip">
           </TableRow>
          <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <Button  android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"  android:layout_marginTop="120dip" android:layout_height="80dip" android:background="@drawable/sched" android:id="@+id/sched"></Button>

        <Button  android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"  android:layout_marginTop="120dip" android:layout_height="80dip" android:background="@drawable/viewsched" android:id="@+id/viewsched"></Button>
               <Button   android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"  android:layout_marginTop="120dip" android:layout_height="80dip" android:background="@drawable/template" android:id="@+id/template"></Button>
       </TableRow>

          <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5" android:layout_width="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="Add new" android:minLines="3" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/text_coutdet_city"></TextView>
          <TextView android:text="View Scheduler" android:minLines="3" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/text_coutdet_city"></TextView>
          <TextView android:text="Message Templates" android:minLines="3" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/text_coutdet_city"></TextView>

          </TableRow>


           <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <Button  android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"  android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="80dip"  android:background="@drawable/upcmng" android:id="@+id/upcmng"></Button>
        <Button   android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"  android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="80dip"  android:background="@drawable/log" android:id="@+id/log"></Button>
               <Button   android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"  android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="80dip"  android:background="@drawable/help" android:id="@+id/help"></Button>
         </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
              <TextView android:text="Upcoming birthdays" android:minLines="3" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/text_coutdet_city"></TextView>
       <TextView android:text="Birthday Log" android:minLines="3" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/text_coutdet_city"></TextView>
       <TextView android:text="Help" android:minLines="3" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/text_coutdet_city"></TextView>
       </TableRow>

      </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new XML File named exactly like your XML File above an put it in a folder named `layout-land`.
This is the XML File which Android will use for your Activity in Ladscape Mode.
Now just change it to match your ideas of the landscape View.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing it.

1. Creating a separate layout as described in docs

> Landscape layout When you want a different design for landscape, put
>   your layout XML file inside /res/layout-land. Android will
>   automatically look here when the layout changes. Without this special
>   landscape layout defined, Android will stretch the default layout.

1. Setting the width and height parameters appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify RelativeLayout parameters, for example:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageVi"
    ...
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ... >
</ImageView>

<TableLayout
    ...
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageVi"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ... >

        ...
</TableLayout>
```